# Problema mysql no vincula

Tags: mysql

tengo un problema a la hora de vincular una tabla con otra por medio de una llave foránea me sale un error no se el por que alguien me ayuda por favor.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE citas (
-> id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
-> fecha DATE NOT NULL,
-> hora TIME NOT NULL,
-> clienteId INT(11) NOT NULL,
-> PRIMARY KEY (id),
-> KEY clienteId (clienteId),
-> CONSTRAINT cliente_FK
-> FOREING KEY (clienteId)
-> REFERENCES clientes (id)
-> );
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREING KEY (clienteId)
REFERENCES clientes (id)
)' at line 9

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se escribe `FOREIGN`

Comment: Muchas gracias.